# update progressbar from OnClickListener inside ArrayAdapter()

Tags: java, android, android-listview, android-arrayadapter

I have the following code in Main.java :

```
public class Main extends Activity implements AdapterView.OnItemClickListener,OnClickListener
{       private ListAdapter adapter;

    int complete;
    ProgressBar progCompleted;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    mListView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list);

    adapter = new MyAdapter(this, R.layout.row, objects);

    mListView.setAdapter(adapter);
    mListView.setOnItemClickListener(this);

    /*
     * Complete rate
     */
    this.complete += (int) getNumberCompleted();
    this.progCompleted = (ProgressBar) findViewById(R.id.ProgBar_completed);
    this.progCompleted.setMax(100);
    this.progCompleted.setProgress(complete);
.......
}
```

And in MyAdapter.java :

```
public class MyAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Task> {

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    rowHolder myHolder= new rowHolder();
    final int mposition = position;

    View v = convertView;

    if (v == null) {
        v = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.row, null);

            myHolder.check_button = (CheckBox) v.findViewById(R.id.CheckButton);
            if(myHolder.check_button != null){
                myHolder.check_button.setChecked(t.isCompleted());

                OnClickListener l =new OnClickListener() {

                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {
                        CheckBox cb = (CheckBox) v;                 
                                            if (cb.isChecked())
                                            {
                                               some task... 
                                             }


                    }
                }; 

                myHolder.check_button.setOnClickListener(l);
            }
    }

    return v;
}
```

So basiclly what I want is to be able to update the progressbar status when I click the CheckBox in the ListView .

Comment: Ok, what have tried? What isn't working?

Comment: Yeah, there's nothing here that needs to get fixed.  What is 'some task...'?

Comment: I didn't need to fix the code ,but to update the ProgressBar from the OnClickListener method in the MyAdapter class.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The easiest way is to create method on your activity which will change your progress bar. As you sent to your adapter activity - call this method with parameter of new value for progress bar.

```
public void setProgress(int mProgressStatus){progCompleted.setProgress(mProgressStatus);}
```

This method on Main activity. 
Create constructor for your adapter with parameter Main mainActivity. 
And then call in your adapter this method `mainActivity.setProgress(35);`(depends from your logic - replace your "some task..." code ).

Hope, this will help you.

With best regards, 
Psycho